# What am i doing wrong with this object method?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to learn javascript objects, starting with a very basic object and I cant get it to work. Can anyone tell me why the last console.log() comes back "undefined" instead of "Bill"??

```js
const firstObject = {
 name: "Bill",
 profession: "Fireman",
 age: 30,
 getInfo: function (theInfo) {
  console.log(theInfo);
  console.log(this.name);
  console.log(this.theInfo);
 },
};
firstObject.getInfo("name");
```

Comment: If `this.name` gets the name, why would `this.theInfo` not get “theInfo”…?

Answer (score 2):

Use `[]` to access the property of object when key is a `string`. See **[Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)**

```js
const firstObject = {
 name: "Bill",
 profession: "Fireman",
 age: 30,
 getInfo: function (theInfo) {
  console.log(theInfo);
  console.log(this.name);
  console.log(this[theInfo]);
 },
};
firstObject.getInfo("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last `console.log` is logging a property not defined on your object since `theInfo` is not a property.

If you want to access a property using a variable, you have to use bracket notation, not dot notation:

```js
const firstObject = {
 name: "Bill",
 profession: "Fireman",
 age: 30,
 getInfo: function (theInfo) {
  console.log(theInfo);
  console.log(this.name);
  console.log(this[theInfo]);
 },
};
firstObject.getInfo("name");
```